# Jquery datatable search and sort not working with .html() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

Hi friends I m having a problem with dataTables search and sort function with i m using the .html() function....to replace the content in a div...the replaced content is coming fro ajax request using this function....

```
function str(gs)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var strArray = xmlhttp.responseText.split("::");
            $("#field1").html(strArray[0]);
            $("#fieldb").html(strArray[1]); //this line replaces the content of tbody where datatables search and sort doesn't work
            $("#tiger1").html(strArray[2]);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "data/readv-data.php?scode="+gs, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

here is the html

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" rel="datatable" id="rep">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Library</th>
            <th>Book</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fieldb">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please supply some more info. Are you saying the data is not appearing at all, meaning the .html() doesn't appear to be working, or is the data appearing but the search/sort not functioning.

If you are seeing the data then press F12 in Chrome, go to the console tab, try searching/sorting and tell me what error(s) you see in the console.

.html() and .text() appear to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/MmbnK/1/ Try alerting strArray[1] to make sure your getting data back as expected and your split is happening as expected.

Comment: the data is coming but the datable sort n search is not functioning....

Comment: How you are using jQuery anyways maybe take a look at jQuery ajax() function.

Answer (score 0):

[DataTables](http://datatables.net/ref) has an API for manipulating/replacing data.  When you replace the  you change the markup, but DataTables doesn't know how to handle it, because you did not tell DataTables that there has been a change.

```
$("#fieldb").html(strArray[1]);

oTable.fnDestroy();
oTable = $('#rep').dataTable();
```

[Best Practices for replacing all table data](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2900/how-to-best-replace-all-table-data/p1)

Comment: It isn't wrking.....so how i m going to tell datatable about the changed markup.....!!!!

Comment: I am having this error after your solution..

ReferenceError: oTable is not defined
 

oTable.fnDestroy();

Comment: @user3139824 `oTable` is the dataTable object that you created.  You did not include this part of your code.  You need to replace `oTable` with correct variable name (which is not given in your question.).